# Timespan calculation

Tags: sql, datetime, sql-server-2014

I have a table like this:

```
#Row  ID  Status1 Status2 TimeStatusChange
------------------------------------------
  1   24    0       0      2020-09-02 09:18:02.233
  2   48    0       0      2020-09-02 09:18:58.540 
  3   24    1       0      2020-09-02 09:19:47.233     
  4   24    0       0      2020-09-02 09:19:47.587     
  5   48    0       1      2020-09-02 09:22:53.923      
  6   36    1       0      2020-09-02 09:24:14.343     
  7   48    0       0      2020-09-02 09:24:49.670     
  8   24    1       0      2020-09-02 09:38:37.820
```

and would like to know, how to calculate the sum of timespans for all status (1 or 2) changes from 0 to 1 (or 1 to 0) grouped by ID.

In this example for ID 24, Status1 from 0 to 1, it would be the difference of TimeStatusChange of #Row 3 and #row 1 + difference of TimeStatusChange of #Row 8 and #row 4, roughly 21 minutes.

The perfect output would look like this:

```
 ID  Change            TimeSpanInMinutes
----------------------------------------
 24  Status1_from_0_1    20
 36  .....
```

Although I have some experience with PL/SQL, I am not getting anywhere.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI  SQL compliant.)

Comment: Specify the datetime values, and expected result as well.

Comment: What if there are multiple rows with 0 before the next 1?

Comment: if there are multiple rows with 0, the row with min(TimeStatusChange) after the last 1  needs to be taken

Comment: And do multiple 1 before 0 exist?

Comment: Possible. In this case we need min(TimeStatusChange) after the last 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sample data**

I added a couple rows to have some more result data and validate the scenario where there are successive rows with the same status for a given ID.

```
declare @data table
(
    ID int, 
    Status1 int,
    Stamp datetime
)

insert into @data (ID, Status1, Stamp) values
(48, 1, '2020-09-02 09:00:00.000'), --added row
(24, 0, '2020-09-02 09:18:02.233'),
(48, 0, '2020-09-02 09:18:58.540'),
(24, 1, '2020-09-02 09:19:47.233'),
(24, 0, '2020-09-02 09:19:47.587'),
(48, 0, '2020-09-02 09:22:53.923'),
(36, 1, '2020-09-02 09:24:14.343'),
(48, 0, '2020-09-02 09:24:49.670'),
(24, 1, '2020-09-02 09:38:37.820'),
(48, 1, '2020-09-02 10:00:00.000'); --added row
```

**Solution**

Uses a common table expression (CTE, `cte_data`) to fetch the previous record for the same ID (regardless of its status value) with the help of the [lag()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql) function. Succeeding rows with the same value as the previous row are removed in the `where` clause outside the CTE.

```
with cte_data as
(
    select  d.ID,
            d.Status1,
            d.Stamp,
            lag(d.Status1) over(partition by d.ID order by d.Stamp) as Status1Prev,
            lag(d.Stamp) over(partition by d.ID order by d.Stamp) as StampPrev
    from @data d
)
select  d.ID,
        d.Status1Prev as Status1From,
        d.Status1 as Status1To,
        sum(datediff(MI, d.StampPrev, d.Stamp)) as StampDiffSumM, --minutes
        convert(time(3), dateadd(MS, sum(datediff(MS, d.StampPrev, d.Stamp)), '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000')) as StampDiffSumF --formatted
from cte_data d
where d.Status1 <> d.Status1Prev
  and d.Status1Prev is not null
group by d.ID, d.Status1Prev, d.Status1
order by d.ID;
```

**Result**

```
ID          Status1From Status1To   StampDiffSumM StampDiffSumF
----------- ----------- ----------- ------------- ----------------
24          0           1           20            00:20:35.233
24          1           0           0             00:00:00.353
48          0           1           36            00:35:10.330
48          1           0           18            00:18:58.540
```

Comment: This leads definitely in the right direction, even if I get only the change from 0 to 1 for status 1.

Comment: I focussed on the 20min for 0to1 example you provided. The new version I added to my answer also gives the 1to0 periods. If you do not need the rows with `null`, then change the `outer apply` to a ´cross apply`.

Comment: And I see, that "order by d2.Stamp desc" takes the latest 0 before a 1. But should be the first 0 after the last 1.

Comment: New solution provided that handles all status changes and allows for successive rows with the same status for a given ID.

Comment: You recognize a master when you see him. Thank you very much!